# How to defer / schedule a retry policy on message receiving from Service Bus?

Tags: azure, servicebus, azure-servicebus-queues, azure-queues

I'm using the new Microsoft library for the service bus (Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus) for .Net core and I'm having trouble trying to find a solution for my problem, this is what I'm trying to accomplish:

My application process a number of different events and sometimes because of a dependency going down I have to store this failed event for later processing, so I created a queue for that and I can send to it without any problems but I'm having a difficult time to receive the event from this queue because I want someway to look at this queue every 5 minutes to see if there is a failed event to process. Is there a way to "schedule" the retrieval of these messages on the queue? I'm reading some guides but they are scheduling the sending process not the receiving one.

Doing a background thread for this application would be a tremendous and hellish task so I would like to know if there is a more practical way to accomplish that, any suggestions are greatly appreciated!

Thank you.

Comment: Take a look at the options presented here: https://www.markheath.net/post/defer-processing-azure-service-bus-message  My assumption is one of the 4 should work.

Comment: I read this article but they all talk about deferring / delaying the send process what I need is a way to read/receive the events from the queue with a scheduled manner i.e "look and consume the events at the queue every 5 minutes."

Comment: Ok.  Sounds like you might need a combination of tagging the message to not be processed for X amount of minutes and then a separate application to process the message.  Lots of options for consuming.  A simple C# application deployed to a Azure function with a timer trigger would be one way.  Or a console application configured to execute every 5 minutes via Windows Task Scheduler.  Largely depends on how/where you want to host.

Comment: *I want someway to look at this queue every 5 minutes to see if there is a failed event to process.* -> why is that? What is preventing you from just processing the message once it arrives using `RegisterMessageHandler` as seen [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-dotnet-get-started-with-queues#receive-messages-from-the-queue)

Comment: Because when an event fails I don't want to process the failed one right away (especially because there are literally thousands of incoming events), and stall the application will jam all the incoming ones while the failed ones are being processed. One way would be doing a second application or a thread but the architecture of the project is really huge and replicate it to a thread would be a hellish task but I think there is no other way